# PHP two dimensional array to HTML input value

Tags: php, html, mysql, multidimensional-array

I am completely new to PHP and this is my first PHP project.
I am doing a degree planner and I have a table for elective courses which has multiple rows for a single user.

I have the following php code

```
<?php
include("config.php");
$db_server = mysql_connect($db_hostname, $db_username, $db_password);

if (!$db_server) die("Unable to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error());

mysql_select_db($db_database, $db_server)
    or die("Unable to select database: " . mysql_error());
session_start();
  $user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
$query_select_elective="SELECT * FROM course_elective WHERE user_id=$user_id";
    $result_course_elective= mysql_query($query_select_elective,$db_server);
      if (!$result_course_elective) die("Database access failed: " . mysql_error());
    $i=0;
    while($row_elective = mysql_fetch_array($result_course_elective))
    {        
        $SubjectCode[$i]['elective_paper_name']=$row_elective[1];
        $SubjectCode[$i]['elective_paper_number']=$row_elective[2];
        $SubjectCode[$i]['elective_paper_grade']=$row_elective[3];
        $SubjectCode[$i]['elective_paper_sem']=$row_elective[4];
        $SubjectCode[$i]['elective_paper_transfer']=$row_elective[5];
        $i++;

    }
echo $SubjectCode[0]['elective_paper_name'];//I get the name of the elective paper fine at this line
echo <<<_END
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Degree Plan</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Assignment1.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <section id="content">
            <form name="degreeplan" method="POST" action="degree_plan_data_science.php">
 <section id="Table">
                    <table class="course_table " style="width:90%" align="center">
<tr class="course_table">
                            <td class="course_table">1</td>
                            <td class="course_table"><input type="text" style="border:none;background:inherit;width:100%" name="elective_paper1" value="$SubjectCode[0]['elective_paper_name']" /></td>
                            <td class="course_table"><input type="text" style="border:none;background:inherit;width:100%" name="elcetive_paper1_number"/></td>
                            <td class="course_table"><input type="text" style="border:none;background:inherit;width:100%" name="sem_elective_paper1"/></td>
                            <td class="course_table"><input type="text" style="border:none;background:inherit;width:100%" name="transfer_elective_paper1"/></td>
                            <td class="course_table"><input type="text" style="border:none;background:inherit;width:100%" name="grade_elective_paper1"/></td>
                        </tr>
```

When I echo the `$SubjectCode[0]['elective_paper_name']` I get it right as OOPS.

However when I want the same value in the input or in other words in the column where I want the elective paper name for `"$SubjectCode[0]['elective_paper_name']"` I am getting `Array['elective_paper_name']` instead of the name of the paper.

Please help.

Comment: One tool you can use to visualize array values is the `print_r` function.  It lets you output the array values to see its structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interpolation is kinda tricky when it comes to arrays.  When an array has a string for a key, you omit the quotes around the key.

`value="$SubjectCode[0][elective_paper_name]"`

Although, there is another method--which is actually preferred for multi-dimensional arrays--that can be used: wrap it in curly brackets.

```
value="{$SubjectCode[0]['elective_paper_name']}"
```

Answer (score 0):

try replacing the value to this :

```
value="<?=$SubjectCode[0]['elective_paper_name']?>"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use brackets around your array and it should work correctly.

change 
`<td class="course_table"><input type="text" style="border:none;background:inherit;width:100%" name="elective_paper1" value="$SubjectCode[0]['elective_paper_name']" /></td>`

to 
`<td class="course_table"><input type="text" style="border:none;background:inherit;width:100%" name="elective_paper1" value="{$SubjectCode[0]['elective_paper_name']}" /></td>`

Comment: Worked... Great Thanks